# I get 0 result and warning mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array

Tags: php, mysql

I get warning **mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array** and get 0 result.

I am sure i have the data, because when i run the same query in phpmyadmin, i get result 1 record.

here is my code

```
   <?php

    require_once('dbConn.php');
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_schedule WHERE status1=0 OR status2=0";
            $resultq = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultq) > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                $notif = 0;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultq)) {
                    $notif = 0;         
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $uid = $row['uid'];
                    $token = $row['token'];
                    $datetime = $row['datetime'];
                    $resvid = $row['resvid'];
                    //....


                    if ($notif == 1) {
                        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
                            echo "Record updated successfully = " . $name;
                        } else {
                            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                        }

                    }


                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }


?>
```

Comment: where's `$sql2`? or is that irrelevant?

Comment: sorry, it's not there because i cut (shorten) the code here because i think that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change this line

```
 $resultq = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
```

to

```
 $resultq = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: ok i will try it. but why i cannot use that mysqli_fetch_array?

Comment: Because [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns array of strings, not `mysqli_result` and as the error states, `mysqli_num_rows()` expects first parameter to be `mysqli_result`.

Answer (score 1):

you get this "**mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result**, array" error because when you use "**mysqli_num_rows($resultq)**" you must supply "**mysqli_result**" which is from "**mysql_query**" [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues), but in your case, you supply the arguments with "**array**" come from "**mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));**" result [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-returnvalues)

in your case, you use

```
$resultq = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
```

this for get schedule

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultq) > 0) {
```

this for check if any schedule

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultq)) {
```

this for fetch it with assoc type, will make waring again because you supply array for the arguments, see **mysqli_fetch_assoc** manual

try this,

```
require_once('dbConn.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_schedule WHERE status1=0 OR status2=0";

/**
* get schedule data with fetch assoc and save it to $rows
*/
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

// check if $rows is not null or empty
if (!empty($rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $notif = 0;

    // loop rows data and call it with row
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $notif = 0;         
        $name = $row['name'];
        $uid = $row['uid'];
        $token = $row['token'];
        $datetime = $row['datetime'];
        $resvid = $row['resvid'];
        //....

        if ($notif == 1) {
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
                echo "Record updated successfully = " . $name;
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }

        }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```